# Earley parser generator for Java

Tags: java, parsing, earley-parser

I'm looking for an [Earley parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earley_algorithm) generator that is able to generate Java output code,
i.e. that generates Java code for the lexer and parser, and allows to include actions
(realised as Java code) that are performed for the grammar rules.

I looked at two Earley parser generators that generate Java code ([Pep](http://www.ling.ohio-state.edu/~scott/#projects-pep) and [PEN](http://linguateca.dei.uc.pt/index.php?sep=recursos))
but none of them seems to allow embedding actions into the grammar.

Answer (score 4):

If I understood your question, by "embed actions in the grammar" you mean inserting semantic actions within the grammar so they are executed "inline" (e.g. during the parsing phase, as the input is being parsed).

Earley parsers are not suitable for this because they allow **any**  context-free language grammars (even ambiguous ones). See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earley_algorithm

Basically: for a given execution and a given state the Earley parser contains **all** possible parsing states. The traditional approach (e.g. Yacc/Bison) is to execute a semantic action after a rule or partial input is matched. But when parsing an ambiguous grammar (e.g. one with a Reduce/Reduce conflict) an Earley parser will take care of both "reductions" and, due to its ambiguity, won't know which action should be executed.

The usual way to use Earley parsers is to parse the input and end up having a *forest* of parse trees on which you later perform the desired actions (e.g. discarding those you know are not valid, or applying some semantic actions or transformations on them).

However, there's been some research on this topic trying to execute some actions inline (sorry, only found this link) https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00236-009-0107-6

Answer (score 1):

> none of them seems to allow embedding actions into the grammar.

Generally speaking, it is not a good idea to embed the actions directly into the grammar. It is better if the actions are decoupled from the grammar.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is an answer, but one of the scanner generators I regularly use is [JFlex](http://www.jflex.de), which outputs Java code.

It works closely with [CUP](http://www2.cs.tum.edu/projects/cup/manual.html), which is a bit closer regarding actions.

Comment: Well, telling from the name (JFlex) and a quick look at the documentation I'd say it's only a lexer and the syntactical analysis part is missing.

Comment: Sure, I added the CUP link which may be a little closer.

Comment: Cheers, will try CUP together with JFlex.

Comment: I know this is from a long time ago, but isn't CUP for creating a LALR parser?  Earley algorithm is for general CFG isn't it?  I was coincidentally looking for the answer to the OP's original question and it seems the answer is still "no such thing" as of 1 year later.